# How can I add a button that toggles a drop down result in React?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, toggle

I'm still learning a lot about React but I'm finding a toggle a lot difficult than I think it should be.

What I'm aiming to achieve is a link titled 'Add Me' that when clicked on shows a a new label that is title 'Added!' having also removed the original 'Add Me' link.

The current code below is what I have, of which I thought would work but it doesn't. I have read A LOT of questions & answers around this simple action, none of which has worked here. Any insight into what I'm doing wrong &/or how to correct it would be extremely helpful!

Thank you in advance!

JSX:

```
class App extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    showComponent: false,
  };
  this.Search__toggle = this.Search__toggle.bind(this);
}

Search__toggle() {
  this.setState({
    showComponent: true,
  });
}

render() {
    return ( 
        <div className="FormField__control">
            <a onClick={this.Search__toggle}><i className="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true" />
                Add Me
            </a>
            {this.state.showComponent ? <div>Added!</div> : null }
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Looks pretty good and straight forward to me ! What is it exactly that doesn't work ?

Comment: @3Dos when I click the link absolutely nothing happens

Comment: Any error showing up in the console ?

Answer (score 0):

You can toggle the **Added!** lable by modifying Search__toggle() method as below

```js
  Search__toggle() {
    let oldState = this.state
    this.setState({
      showComponent: !oldState.showComponent,
    });
  }
```

Further, if you want to hide the **Add Me** link modify the render() method as below

```js
render() {
      return ( 
          <div className="FormField__control">
              {this.state.showComponent ? 
                <div>Added!</div> :
                <a onClick={this.Search__toggle}><i className="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true" />
                  Add Me
                </a> 
              }
          </div>
      );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there :-). Not sure you `Search__toggle` is the right name for your function since you don't want to toggle the element but rather add it once.

```js
class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showComponent: false,
    };
    this.addItem = this.addItem.bind(this);
  }

  addItem() {
    this.setState({
      showComponent: true,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return ( 
        <div className="FormField__control">
            { this.state.showComponent ?
            "Added"
            :
            <a onClick={this.addItem}>
              <i className="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true" />Add Me
            </a>
            }
        </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App name="World" />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

If however you'd like to rather toggle your element, here is another version.

```js
class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showComponent: false,
    };
    this.Search__toggle = this.Search__toggle.bind(this);
  }

  Search__toggle() {
    this.setState({
      showComponent: !this.state.showComponent,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return ( 
        <div className="FormField__control">
            { this.state.showComponent ?
            <a onClick={this.Search__toggle}>
              <i className="fa fa-minus" aria-hidden="true" />Added
            </a>
            :
            <a onClick={this.Search__toggle}>
              <i className="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true" />Add Me
            </a>
            }
        </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App name="World" />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hello @TobiAjala, was that helpful? Please let me know if you need more information, I'll be glad to help.